# Connecting to a localhost:3000 server with Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, localhost, server

I'm using express and node. I start my application and run it on `port:3000`

I want to test the site on a iPad without pushing or building a stage site. This is just me testing new packages etc. and want to test on iPad.

So is there a way I can connect to a `localhost` from another computer, iPad or phone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you do have firewall issues, or if the device you want to test from isn't on the same network, you can use a tool called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

You run ngrok specifying a port, eg `ngrok 3000` and it will make your localhost service internet visible at an address with the form `https://12345.ngrok.com`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first of all you need to find out your IP.

Depending on your OS that can be ifconfig or ipconfig or ip addr or etc :)

Secondly you have to make sure you have no firewall on your PC (such as Fedora's or Windows' personal firewalls), or that it is configured to allow connections to that port.

After that you go to any other device connected to the same network and go to http://yourip:3000 .

If you give me more info, such as your OS, I could try to be more specific.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm on Mac running OS X Yosemite v10.10.2

Comment: Okay then ifconfig will do the trick. look for the en0 interface (your ip is the "inet" one) if you're connected by cable. You can also find it in the network window in the Settings app. Aaaaanddd... I guess there's no firewall enabled by default, try that, it should work.